# It position in sentence

Tags: conjunctions, ambiguity

How to recognize which subject or object **"it"** is referring to in the following sentence:

> The Pump gives 10 bar pressure to the Machine and **it** will give good
>   production.

Here how can we identify whether the pronoun "it" refers to the Pump or the Machine.

This is my confusion that I want to be clear how to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3 ambiguous pronouns by Justice Antonin Scalia](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42741/3-ambiguous-pronouns-by-justice-antonin-scalia)

Comment: It's ambiguous. Most *likely* it's referring to the pump. If it were referring to the Machine it would probably be written as *and* ***enables*** *it*. To be explicit, it could have been written as *The Pump* ***both*** *gives*. (The sentence as a whole, however, uses different verb forms so has a problem with parallelism.)

Answer (score -1):

According to **The Law Of Proximity**, the "***it***" in your example

> The Pump gives 10 bar pressure to the Machine and it will give good production.

refers to

> **machine**

Meaning, the machine when it receives 10 bar of pressure is capable of good production.

"***It***" is closest to **machine**, otherwise the author might have written

> The Machine receives 10 bar pressure from the Pump, and it will give good production.

unless some other context is given

> The Pump gives 10 bar pressure to the Machine and it will give good production to other machines that need pressure.

Also, since the production of the pump is already mentioned, it can be assumed by *context* that the **pump** has good (sufficient) production.